# Accessing Ember data has-many relationship on template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

I have a rails back-end, serving data as per the JSON API standards (jsonapi-resources gem). I have two models: Contact and PhoneNumber.

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :phone_numbers
end

class PhoneNumber < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

This is the JSON response for the API endpoint.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "6",
            "type": "phone-numbers",
            "links": {
                "self": "http://localhost:3000/phone-numbers/6"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "name": "byeworld",
                "phone-number": "9212098"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "contact": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "http://localhost:3000/phone-numbers/6/relationships/contact",
                        "related": "http://localhost:3000/phone-numbers/6/contact"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

These are my Ember models:

for contact:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  nameFirst: DS.attr('string'),
  nameLast: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  twitter: DS.attr('string'),
  phoneNumbers: DS.hasMany('phone-number', {async: true, inverse: 'contact'})
});
```

for phone-number:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  phoneNumber: DS.attr('string'),
  contact: DS.belongsTo('contact', {async: true, inverse: 'phoneNumbers'})
});
```

This is my route handler:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('contact', params.contact_id, {include: "phone-numbers"});
  },
  (...)
});
```

I am unable to access the phone-numbers for a contact on the template by doing:

```
{{#each model.phoneNumbers as |phone|}}
  {{phone.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Also, the data for the phone-numbers exists in the ember console. What am I missing?

Comment: What is your ember-data version ?

Comment: `"ember-data": "~2.14.3"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is open known issue in ember-data version 2.14.3. so please downgrade your ember-data version to 2.13.2 . that might solve your issue.

Refer this ember-data open issue - https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4942

Answer (score 0):

`model.PhoneNumbers` => `model.phoneNumbers`

If this is not just this typo, try extending your model serializer / adapter from the JSON API adapters / serializers (or do it on you application serializer / adapter if all your models use it):

`import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({});`

and:

`import JSONAPISerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/json-api';
export default JSONAPISerializer.extend({});`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sorry for the typo. It didn't help. I don't know if this will help but I am getting `You modified "model.phoneNumbers" twice on <front-end@model:contact::ember348:3> in a single render.` and  `Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined` errors in the console.

Comment: I now have an application.js in `app/adapters` with the code from your first suggestion in it. Sadly there's no improvement.